# Underlined title in Firefox tabs

Tags: firefox, tabs, underline

Sometimes at several webpages I have underlined title of page in my Firefox tabs ([here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJDJu.png)).

I have two questions related to this:

1. What mean this underline?
2. Is it possible, to do it from web page level (via CSS or JS)?

It's Firefox for MacOS, but I'm not sure if it does matter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using, by any chance, [Firefox Multi-Account Container](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/)? If so the color of the line which underlines the title indicates the container the page is opened in.

I don't think you could change the color of the underline from unprivileged JS/CSS (web page), but I could be wrong. This is the source code for [Firefox Multi-Account Container](https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers). Within that repository, you might be able to find the location where the underlining happens. For example, it could be [this CSS code](https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/blob/99db19279225664f943df7c873e01c355c875b26/data/usercontext.css#L9).

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. I found that underlines in tabs are made by extension facebook-container.